# Prove or disprove: If $a^2 \mid bc$, then $a \mid b$ or $a \mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove or disprove: If $a^2 \mid bc$, then $a \mid b$ or $a \mid c$.

I have not been able to find a counter example so I am thinking it may be true. I started by thinking that since $a^2 \mid bc$, $bc = a^2k$ for some integer $k$. Then if we divide by $a$, we get $\dfrac{bc}{a} = ak$. Since $ak \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\dfrac{bc}{a} \in \mathbb{Z} \Longrightarrow b/a \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $c/a \in \mathbb{Z} \Longrightarrow a \mid b$ or $a \mid c$.

This seems a little weird so I am not sure if it works or not. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

$36|36=9\cdot4$ but $6$ does not divide $9$ or $4$

Comment: don't know how I missed that one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure, happy to help.